# "prospect" and "future" in the same sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Consider the next sentence:

> I chose X in order to bridge the gap between Y and Z, with the **prospect** of working on N in the **future**.

Is it correct to use the word **prospect**, which according to Cambridge dictionary means "*the idea of something that will or might happen in the future*", and the word **future** at the same time in a sentence? Or is there a better way to say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is acceptable, and fluent speakers do this frequently. Strictly speaking, it is a redundancy, and the words "in the future" can be omitted with little change of meaning, although their presence emphasizes "future"and suggests that the prospect is not immediate. With "in the future" omitted, there is an implication that the prospect is rather near-term or immediate.